# Swift combining code

Tags: swift

I am coding an app with Xcode/Swift. I want to combine these 2 functions of code into one smaller function of code to eliminate duplicate code.

First section of code:

```
@IBAction func StopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
     recordButton.isEnabled = true
     stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
     recordingLabel.text = "Tap to record"
     audioRecorder.stop()
     let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
     try! audioSession.setActive(false)
}
```

The second section of code:

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    recordingLabel.text = "Recording in progress"
    stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
    recordButton.isEnabled = false
```

Here is my bad attempt:

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        func SetLabel(recordButton: Bool, recordingText:String)
        if recordButton = true
            recordingLabel.text = "Recording in progress"
            stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
            recordButton.isEnabled = false
    else if {
        @IBAction func StopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
            recordButton.isEnabled = true
            stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
            recordingLabel.text = "Tap to record"
            audioRecorder.stop()
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try! audioSession.setActive(false)
        }
                }

    {
```

Comment: OK, what's your issue? Where's your attempt to combine them? What problem are you having with that attempt?

Comment: There aren't any common lines of code to make it worthwhile refactoring.

Comment: combine these 2 functions into one, not combine 2 lines of code...

Comment: Do you have a reason for wanting them combined?  (I honestly can't think of one.)

Comment: The goal is to refactor repetitive code. As you can see they're sharing this same logic - setting up two buttons and one label. So why not try to refactor it into a single method with parameters?

Here is a sample solution

func setUIState(isRecording:Bool, recordingText:String)
{
here based on parameters we can setup label and buttons
}

when the method is ready - you can replace the code with a single line with the accurate parameter.
Hope that will be helpful.
51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
func updateButtons(recording: Bool) {
    recordingLabel.text = recording ? "Recording in progress" : "Tap to record"
    stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = recording
    recordButton.isEnabled = !recording
}
```

Comment: What IBaction would this code go under? Or is this a seperate function to use in the IBaction

Comment: it is a separate function, your StopRecording body would be like: @IBAction func StopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
    updateButtons(recording: false)
    // plus whatever left to be done
}

Comment: @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject) {
         updateButtons(recording: <#T##Bool#>)

Comment: @TraeShanks Instead of yelling thanks, indicate the answer solved your issue by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.